# S3 Presigned URL for large files not working - python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare's R2 storage (s3 compatible), and the pre-signed URL for downloading files from a private bucket works well for files smaller than 1GB. When the file size is more than 1GB it returns access denied.

**Code to generate pre-signed URL is here:**

```
temp_link = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',Params={'Bucket': bucketName,'Key': File_key, 'ResponseContentDisposition': 'attachment'},ExpiresIn=3600*8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Presigned URLs are not valid when the credentials that generated them are no longer valid. So in case of a role, when the Assume Role Credentials expire, the Presigned URL is no longer valid. 
You can also try using Multi-part upload for uploading large files (> 5GB) via multiple parts.

Answer (score 0):

After spending an hour, finally, I fixed it...hope it may help others.

The issue was not with the file or file size, My file name contains **"&"** character(s). Due to this, the pre-signed URL is breaking (without '&' escaping it will not figure out GET params correctly).

*So the moral of the story is...never use "&" characters in the file names (OR implement proper escaping)*

It was a nightmare.